# xpath to solve using local-name() value

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I am having this xml need to parse using xpath 
I want to know that how I can get xpath which will give me child value from parent I am getting parent node value from

```
//*[local-name()='BucketCategory']
```

but need its value from BucketBalance so that I can use it dynamically
XML is

```
<xsdLocal1:T2BucketBalanceResponse xmlns:xsdLocal1="http://www.tele2.com/T2BucketBalanceResponse_05.00">
<xsdLocal1:Header>
    <xsdLocal1:MessageId>654321</xsdLocal1:MessageId>
    <xsdLocal1:ConversationId>2aeba17d-e9c2-11e4-b061-f5ff8e3ab34b</xsdLocal1:ConversationId>
    <xsdLocal1:BusinessProcessId/>
    <xsdLocal1:MessageTargetNamespace>http://www.tele2.com/T2BucketBalanceResponse</xsdLocal1:MessageTargetNamespace>
    <xsdLocal1:MessagePriority>4</xsdLocal1:MessagePriority>
    <xsdLocal1:Timestamp>2015-05-01 09:26:12.887</xsdLocal1:Timestamp>
    <xsdLocal1:Sender>TIP</xsdLocal1:Sender>
    <xsdLocal1:Recipient>SiebelCRM_NL</xsdLocal1:Recipient>
    <xsdLocal1:LegalEntity>27</xsdLocal1:LegalEntity>
    <xsdLocal1:PayloadEncoding>Plain</xsdLocal1:PayloadEncoding>
</xsdLocal1:Header>
<xsdLocal1:BucketBalance>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketCategory>VMRC_R2</xsdLocal1:BucketCategory>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketAmount>200.0</xsdLocal1:BucketAmount>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketLevel>Service</xsdLocal1:BucketLevel>
    <xsdLocal1:AllocationStartDate>03/25/2015 00:00:00</xsdLocal1:AllocationStartDate>
</xsdLocal1:BucketBalance>
<xsdLocal1:BucketBalance>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketCategory>VMRC_Rertet</xsdLocal1:BucketCategory>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketAmount>456.0</xsdLocal1:BucketAmount>
    <xsdLocal1:BucketLevel>sdfsdff</xsdLocal1:BucketLevel>
    <xsdLocal1:AllocationStartDate>03/25/2015 00:00:00</xsdLocal1:AllocationStartDate>
</xsdLocal1:BucketBalance>
```

Comment: "*which will give me child value from parent I am getting parent node value from*"... can you explain a bit more? And provide the expected result against your sample input file? Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output? If you meant to get parent of `//*[local-name()='BucketCategory']`, then try : `//*[local-name()='BucketCategory']/..`

Comment: Interpreting "*need its value from BucketBalance*" to mean that you've established that the current context is some `BucketBalance` element and are wondering then how to select ***its*** `BucketCategory` child, you simply would use this XPath:  `*[local-name()='BucketCategory']`